# Passive Level Shifter Needed - LVCMOS 3.3

Tags: voltage-divider, interface, lvcmos

The device that will be driving another device claims it is LVCMOS 3.3V but it doesn't appear to be. Here are the voltage levels of both parts:

VoH(min)= 2.3V
VoL(max)=0.8V
ViH(min) = 2.0V
ViL(max) = 0.8V

The problem is with the VoL-ViL where there is no margin. The device which is driving the other device realizes this and recommends a voltage divider like this[image: Voltage divider]

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work because now at VoH=2.3V, the ViH=1.56V which is below 2.0V.

I tried other combinations of resistor values but nothing working.

Can anyone recommend a way to get this interface to work with passive components?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is actually a problem? If the Vol is specified with a current and the actual input supplies no input the Vol will be essentially at the internal ground potential of the chip doing the driving. BTW, convention is that signal flows from left to right!

Comment: What is the direction of current flow, from FPGA to SVTL or SVTL to FPGA?

Comment: So this is the drawing I got from the datasheet which I agree is backwards from what I am used to. The output is the SVTL side and the FPGA is the input side.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. Can you elaborate on your response? The receiver datasheet does not specify input current but I know the Iol current from the driver

Comment: Typically the CMOS output behaves resistively at relatively low voltage difference from the rail, so if it drops 800mV at 8mA maximum, it will drop 100mV at 1mA maximum. You have to be a bit careful because the internal rail may not be at exactly the same potential as the power rail pin.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. I found out that the vendor does not recommend the voltage divider and just connect directly which would mean that the Vol=Vil=0.8V with no noise margin. So to your point above if the output Iol=80uA and the Iil= 1uA, that would seem like the Vol would not go near the 0.8V correct? Is there a calculation you can make to see how high it could go?